# Run and await a coroutine as a task

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, async-await

I'm trying to move away from unity's coroutines and callbacks in favor of async/await.

I have the following code using coroutines:

```cs
public IEnumerator GetProfileJson(string address, GetProfileSuccess onSuccess, GetProfileFailed onFail)
{
    var queryRequest = new QueryUnityRequest<GetDataFunction, GetDataOutputDTO>(RpcUrl, null);
    yield return queryRequest.Query(new GetDataFunction(), address);
    if(queryRequest.Result == null)
    {
        onFail?.Invoke(new NullResponseException());
        yield break;
    }

    byte[] resultBytes = queryRequest.Result.Values[0]; 
    string url = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultBytes);

    using WebClient web = new WebClient();  
    string json = web.DownloadString(url);

    onSuccess?.Invoke(json);
}
```

I would like to convert it to something like this:

```cs
public async Task<string> GetProfileJson(string address)
{
    var queryRequest = new QueryUnityRequest<GetDataFunction, GetDataOutputDTO>(RpcUrl, null);
    
    await Task.Run(() => // Somehow await this coroutine's completion
    {           
        queryRequest.Query(new GetDataFunction(), address);
    });
    
    if(queryRequest.Result == null)
    {
        throw new NullResponseException();
        yield break;
    }
    
    byte[] resultBytes = queryRequest.Result.Values[0]; 
    string url = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultBytes);
    
    using WebClient web = new WebClient();  
    string json = await web.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
    
    return json;
}
```

But I just can't figure out how to run and await this line
`queryRequest.Query(new GetDataFunction(), address);`

The Query method is from [Neuthereum's API](https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum/blob/master/src/Nethereum.Unity/QueryUnityRequest.cs) and looks like this

```cs
public IEnumerator Query(string contractAddress, BlockParameter blockParameter = null)
{
    yield return Query(new TFunctionMessage(), contractAddress, blockParameter);
}
```

Comment: I guess returning the IEnumerator is the closest you can get to async/await. Because Query() does not return a IAsyncResult (or Task) it can't be awaited. Apparently, the API is too old. Since I don't know the library, I can't tell if it has a newer version of this API or an alternative API that supports async/await. Unless you discover a async implementation, you will have to use `yield return`. Also be aware that `WebClient` is deprecated. Microsoft recommends to avoid it in favor of the modern [HttpClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0).

Comment: @Rurre were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @r4ravi2008 Unfortunately not.